# Roku Labellist icon misaligned

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have an application with a label list. If local images are provided as "HDLISTITEMICONURL" then icon is aligned to text. But when we use remote images as icon url, then the icon is misaligned.
Is there any fix for the same?

Comment: Can you post a minimal code sample?

Comment: sounds like a difference with either the images themselves or their poster field settings.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation provided by Roku does not seem to allow any adjustment of where the icon appears. Whenever I run into issues like this, I will write my own code to fix the problem. For example, the RowList has a field showRowCounter. It also even has a field that is supposed to control where the counter will appear (that does not work). I ended up just leaving it set to false and created my own Label node and wrote a little extra code to handle changing the text. It's tedious and annoying, AKA programming a channel on Roku. Hope this helped.